# How to get the value of String Array?

Tags: java

I want to print the String Array. This is my Code:

```c#
System.out.println(WMSLoggerFactory.getGlobalLogValue(WMSLoggerIDs.FD_ALL));
```

I got this error:

```
The method getGlobalLogValue(String) in the type WMSLoggerFactory is not applicable for the arguments (String[])
```

How can I print this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use for loop:

```
for(String s : WMSLoggerIDs.FD_ALL) {
     System.out.println(WMSLoggerFactory.getGlobalLogValue(s));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a `WMSLoggerFactory` is, but I suspect it's going to want a String.  One simple way to convert an Array into a sensible looking string is the `Arrays.toString` method, which will create a string that looks something like

```
["foo", "bar", "bletch"]
```

In this case, you could call it as

```
System.out.println(WMSLoggerFactory.getGlobalLogValue(Arrays.toString(WMSLoggerIDs.FD_ALL)));
```

---

That said, I don't think your question is particularly clear.  Judging by that method name, it's going to want some sort of key, not a string representation of an array.  What *exactly* are you trying to print out, and why do you need the `WMSLoggerFactory` to do this?

Comment: i want to receive the all Log fields by using this method